# Удаление символов

Tags: java

Имеется следующий код:

```
package com.company;
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] arr = {"+5", "-3"};
        int a = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i<arr.length; i++){
            if (arr[i].contains("+")){
                arr[i].replace('+',' ');
            }

            else if (arr[i].contains("-")){
                arr[i].replace('-',' ');
            }
            System.out.print(arr[i]+" ");
        }

    }
}
```

Задача программы - изъятие элемента массива, определение знака для вычисления и последующее вычисление. a - начальное число. Другого способа удаления +/-, после определения знака, не нашёл, но и этот не работает. В чём ошибка?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Не работает, потому что строки *неизменяемые*. Вы пытаетесь в строке `arr[i]` заменить `+` на пробел, но он не заменится, вместо этого метод `replace` *вернёт* вам *новую строку*, в которой `+` будут заменены на пробел. Соответственно чтобы код работал, нужно писать так:

```
arr[i] = arr[i].replace('+',' ');
```

Answer (score 1):

Предлагаю такое решение, учитывая что a с типом int, т.е. не дробное, то результат будет с усечением:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] arr = {"+5", "-3", "*5", "/2", "%2"};
        int a = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i<arr.length; i++){
            // получим знак операции
            char sign = arr[i].toCharArray()[0];
            // получим число, и произведём автораспаковку в примитив int
            int num = Integer.valueOf(arr[i].substring(1));
            // условия для знака операции 
            switch(sign){
                case '+' : a += num; break;
                case '-' : a -= num; break;
                case '*' : a *= num; break;
                case '/' : a /= num; break;
                case '%' : a %= num; break;
            }
        }
        // результат
        System.out.print(String.format("Result: %d", a));
    }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Поскольку вы задаете числа строками, можно их конвертировать встроенными средствами:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] arr = {"+5", "-3"};
    int result = 0;
    for (String numStr : arr) {
        result += Integer.parseInt(numStr);
    }

    System.out.println(result);
}
```